# Solving Recurrence Equation $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_n)$

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

How to solve following recurrence equation

$$a_0=2$$
$$a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_n)$$

I tried:

```
sol=RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]

ListPlot[{sol}]
```

but it doesn't work.

how to find the sequence $a_n$?

Comment: By the way, where did you encounter this recurrence relation?

Answer (score 11):

Your recurrence is an instance of the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) $$x_{n+1} = r x_n(1 - x_n).$$

The first sentence of the [**Solution in some cases**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_in_some_cases) section in the link above says:

> The special case of r = 4 can in fact be solved exactly, as can the case with r = 2; however the general case can only be predicted statistically.

*Mathematica* is indeed able to solve the $r=2$ and $r=4$ cases:

```
RSolve[a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[n], n]
```

> ```
> {{a[n] -> 1/2 - 1/2 E^(2^n C[1])}}
> ```

```
RSolve[a[n + 1] == 4 a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[n], n]
```

> ```
> {{a[n] -> 1/2 - 1/2 Cos[2^n C[1]]}}
> ```

So I *think* no one really knows a proper closed form of your nonlinear recurrence.

In fact the wiki link makes it seem like the solution is highly dependent on the initial condition, i.e. a small change in the initial condition will result in a large change in the solution.

### Edit

A quick search on OEIS *almost* gives us a closed form. [A007018](https://oeis.org/A007018) gives the formula

$$a(n) = -\left\lfloor c^{2^n} \right\rfloor,$$

where

$$c = 1.597910218031873178338070118157\ldots$$

Now the issue here is knowing the precise value of $c$. In fact we need to know many decimal places of $c$ to be able to find the first few values of $a(n)$.

[A077125](https://oeis.org/A077125/constant) gives the first 105 digits and that's only enough to give us the first $8$ values of $a(n)$:

```
c = 1.59791021803187317833807011815745531236222495318211419659139309422961619562279496876114706281963518250566;

SetAttributes[sol, Listable];

sol[0] = 2;
sol[n_] := -Floor[c^(2^n)]

correct = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[0] == 2}, a[n], {n, 0, 10}]];

(* relative error *)
1. - sol[Range[0, 10]]/correct
```

> ```
> {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 5.92121*10^-103, 1.18326*10^-102}
> ```

So I guess this is a way to approximate solutions and I imagine that's what the quote from above ***"can only be predicted statistically"*** means.

Comment: and even for r = - 2.

Answer (score 3):

Form [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114071/archimedes-scheme-to-find-pi)
you should use: `RecurrenceTable`

```
 sol = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[0] == 2}, a[n], {n, 0, 6}]
```

with result:

> {2, -2, -6, -42, -1806, -3263442, -10650056950806}

And plot:

```
ListLogPlot[Abs[sol], Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd have just used `NestList[# (1 - #) &, 2, 6]` myself.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most compact, but you can define recursive functions like this :

```
a[0] = 2;
a[n_] := a[n - 1] (1 - a[n - 1]);
Table[a[k], {k, 0, 6}]
(* {2, -2, -6, -42, -1806, -3263442, -10650056950806} *)
```

If you care about speed/efficiency just add memoization to make it run in linear time:

```
a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] (1 - a[n - 1]);
```

Comment: n^2 complexity, gah! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `RSolve` is unable to yield a result for

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]
```

If we apply a multiplier of 2 it gives an answer

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] (1 - a[n]), a[0] == 2}, a[n], n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would be most interested to understand why the former has no solution using `RSolve`. Note that removing the boundary condition doesn't result in an answer.

### Fast recursive function

Since `RSolve` doesn't work we can at least define a function that will give the desired answer.

Below is a copy of one from **A.G.**'s answer

```
a[0] = 2;
a[n_] := a[n - 1] (1 - a[n - 1]);
```

and a faster version that uses `Fold`.

```
af[n_Integer /; n > -1] := Fold[# (1 - #) &, 2, Range[n]]
```

**Timing Test**

```
a[16]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.16, Null} *)

af[16]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0001, Null} *)
```